# Economics-utility function

Tags: functions, economics, monotone-functions, utility

We let $g(z)$ be a strictly monotonous function so:
$$\frac{dg(z)}{dz}>0$$
Consumer 1 has preferences given by the utility function $u(x_1,x_2)=ln(x_1)+2ln(x_2)$, while consumer 2 has preferences given by n $v(x_1,x_2)=g(x_1x_2^2)$.
Then I have to show that consumer 2 got same preferences as consumer 1.
I think I have to use MSR on $x_1x_2^2$ and on $v(x_1,x_2)$. For MSR on $x_1x_2^2$  I get:
$$MRS=-\frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}}{\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}}=-\frac{x_2^2}{2x_1x_2}$$
But How can I find MSR on $v(x_1,x_2)$ (maybe with the chain rule?) and use this to conclude that the ranking of the two indifference curves is the same when $g(z)$ is monotonous?
I hope that someone can help me?

Comment: Did you try the chain rule?

Comment: I think when I use the chain rule, then I get MRS and when I find MRS by $u(x_1,x_2)=ln(x_1)+2ln(x_2)$. Can you help what I can conclude by that?

Comment: Try simplifyiing the expression for the MRS that you found. That should give you a hint. Then use the chain rule to find the MRS of $g(v(x_1,x_2))$.

Comment: @Trurl Computing the MRS is not needed; see my reply

Answer (score 1):

Observe consumer 2's utility is a positive monotonic transformation of consumer 1's utility:

$$v(x_1,x_2)=g(e^{u(x_1x_2)}),$$

and you are done.